# Loop through several text files with a multiple line regex in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I'm trying to seach through several textfiles with a regex. I've managed to get it working when the regex matches on a single row but when I test with a regex that match on one row and end of another row, it doesn't work.

I've read that you first need to read the entire file to a variable/array and then do the regex search. I've not managed to get this to work.

The structure of the folders and files are

```
Root Folder
├─17-11-01
│ ├─trace-0.log
│ └─trace-1.log
└─17-11-02
  ├─trace-0.log
  └─trace-1.log
```

I have managed to get the full path to the files but I'm not sure how I read the content of the file. I found `[IO.File]::ReadAllText($Path)` but am not sure how I add it to the command below.

```
Get-ChildItem $Path -Filter $Filter -Recurse |
    Select FullName |
    ft -HideTableHeaders
```

To summarize what I'm trying to do.

- Do a regex search where the matched text will span multiple lines.
- Multiple files in multiple paths under the same root.
- Count each of the regex matches.

I'm currently using PowerShell v2 on Windows 7 but I can upgrade to v4. The script will mostly be used on Windows 10 and Windows Server 2012 R2 and later.

**Edit 1**
Here is an example of the log file and the regex.

```
FINER: Entering service: ABC  
2017-11-03T08:22:18.557+0100 - INFO: Some info.
2017-11-03T08:22:18.557+0100 - INFO: Some info.
2017-11-03T08:22:18.557+0100 - INFO: Some info.
2017-11-03T08:22:18.557+0100 - INFO: Some info.
2017-11-03T08:22:18.557+0100 - INFO: Some info.
2017-11-03T08:22:18.557+0100 - INFO: Some info.
2017-11-03T08:22:18.557+0100 - INFO: The request has been completed.
```

```
(2017-10-.*FINER\: Entering service: (ABC |ABC1|ABC2))[\s\S]*?(INFO: \d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d The request has been completed)
```

Comment: Store the files in a variable. Why do you try to get a oneliner command?

Comment: @guiwhatsthat I don't need to do it in a oneliner. I've tested it with more lines by splitting the commands without any luck.

Comment: first read the log with [iO.File]::ReadAllLines() than loop through all lines and do your regex search

Comment: @guiwhatsthat Alright. How do I get the filenames and use them in that command? When I use Get-ChildItem $Path -Filter $Filter -Recurse | Select FullName | ft -HideTableHeaders I get the full paths to the files. But when I use it it seems that powershell sees it as one large path and not seperate paths.

Comment: Just use Get-ChildItem $Path -Filter $Filter -Recurse | Select FullName and you will get an array back

Comment: Read the file into a single string (`Get-Content | Out-String`), then use `Select-String` for matching the content against a regular expression. With that said, your regular expression does not match your sample data. At all.

Comment: @ChristofferL - trying some mindreading here but this might get you started again: `^FINER: Entering service: .*$(\n.*)*?The request has been completed.`

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Thanks, got a little further. The regex I got works fine, I've tested it in Notepad++. I couldn't post the original log file so I had to edit it and the regex. This results in 1 with different regex that works in Notepad++.
_$Files = (Get-ChildItem $PathSign -Filter $FilterSign -Recurse | Get-Content | Out-String)
(Select-String -inputObject $Files -pattern $Regex -AllMatches).count_
LievenKeersmaekers Thanks but the regex is working fine in Notepad++.

Comment: Again, it's not possible that the regular expression you posted could match the sample data you posted.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers That might be true but the original regex will match the data in the log file, I've used it several times in Notepad++. Lets focus on the command and assume that the regex is correct.

Comment: If you expect us to help you need to provide sample data that actually resembles the log data your regular expression is supposed to match.

Comment: So you actually want to convert the `notepad++` regex syntax to `powershell's` syntax? Notepad++ uses the [standard PCRE (Perl) syntax](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions). You might try this suggested conversion from regexbuddy: `(2017-10-[^\n]*FINER: Entering service: (ABC |ABC1|ABC2))[\t\n\f\r \S]*?(INFO: [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] The request has been completed)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit 2 Solution**

Here is the final code. The regex is in my example didn't match the the example log.

```
$Files = (Get-ChildItem $Path -Filter $FilterFile -Recurse | Get-Content | Out-String)

(Select-String -inputObject $Files -pattern $Regex -AllMatches).Matches.Count
```

The expression worked just fine, that was not the issue.

Thanks!